# How to change poller frequency at runtime within a Http outbound gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

My scenario is a Http outbound gateway where I ask an external service for the next transition represented by a `TransferRequest` entity. The gateway is the endpoint of the "httpOutRequest" channel. The startpoint for "httpOutRequest" channel is a bean `IntegrationFlow source()` where I send an empty String message triggered by a poller. (Btw: Is this necessary? Could I add the poller directly to the Outbound Gateway? How?)

Then I have installed the errorHandler channel endpoint to catch any problem. If the number of problems (Exceptions) is `MAX_COUNT_TO_REDUCE_POLLING` - let's say because the external service is not accessible - then I would like to reduce polling from initally 5_000 to 60_000, at runtime.

Here is my code so far:

```
    public static final int MAX_COUNT_TO_REDUCE_POLLING = 3;

    private long period = 5000;
    private int problemCounter = 0;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outbound() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("httpOutRequest")
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/harry-potter-service/next/request")
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .expectedResponseType(TransferRequest.class)
                        )
                .channel("reply")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow source() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                () -> new GenericMessage<String>(""),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedRate(period)))
                .channel("httpOutRequest")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "reply")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("myHandler: " + message.getPayload());
                System.out.println("myHandler: " + message.getHeaders());
                TransferRequest req = (TransferRequest) message.getPayload();
                System.out.println("myHandler: " + req);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public MessageHandler errorHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                LOG.error("message.payload: " + message.getPayload());
                MessageHandlingException e = (MessageHandlingException) message.getPayload();
                LOG.error("Exception: " + e);
                LOG.debug("exception counter = " + (++problemCounter));

                if (problemCounter >= MAX_COUNT_TO_REDUCE_POLLING) {
                    LOG.debug("would like to reduce poller frequence or stop");
                    period = 60_000;
                //  outbound().stop()
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

How can I reduce polling frequence at runtime when the threshold number of exceptions has been encountered?

How could I even stop the Integration flow?

**EDIT 1**

More specific: If I have a Messaging Gateway

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow source() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            () -> new GenericMessage<String>(""),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedRate(period)))
            .channel("httpOutRequest")
            .get();
}
```

How do I access the p within the second Lambda?

How can I set `p.fixedRate` using a `Control Channel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have solved this problem by myself, reading the manual.

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#polling-consumer-change-polling-rate) to change pollig rate at runtime. To do that you have to use the `DynamicPeriodiyTimer` from the `org.springframework.integration.util` package.

To replace your delayed poller, do:

```
    private final DynamicPeriodicTrigger dynamicPeriodicTrigger =
            new DynamicPeriodicTrigger(5_000);

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow normalStateEntryPoint() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                () -> new GenericMessage<String>(""),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(dynamicPeriodicTrigger))
                        .id("normalStateSourcePollingChannelAdapter")
                        .autoStartup(true))
                .channel("httpOutRequest")
                .get();
    }
```

To reduce polling from 5.000 to 60.000 milliseconds, do:

```
    dynamicPeriodicTrigger.setPeriod(60_000);
```

That's it.

Comment: No, I don’t speak speak like, so you need to revise your answer according code of conduct over here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct. At the same time you are right about that approach to be able to change period at runtime

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought putting stars to the credit card number makes it secure against abuse... It was more against my hard understanding, not against you! I will revise my answer. Thanks a lot, Artem! I appreciate a lot what you guys are doing here.